# WordPress admin sends empty response but frontend works

Tags: wordpress

All my WordPress installs suddenly have wp-admin inaccessible after installing. I've repeated the procedure several times, and in different locations to avoid caching issues.

Steps:

1. download WP from the official site
2. do a fresh install in an empty database
3. log in to /wp-admin

After logging in I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and in the console I see the error "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." After this the admin section is completely inaccessible.

The site itself however works fine and I see the default Hello World post.

My existing WP install run fine, but any new ones I make behave as described.

I have tried rebooting and restarting Apache.

I am on MacOS, PHP 7.3.29.

Comment: Are you on windows? php version? wordpress version? Docker is the solution. Are you open to docker?

Comment: WP version is the current one – freshly downloaded from the official site. I'm on MacOS. The strange thing is my existing WP install work fine, but any new ones I make behave as I described. PHP 7.3.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly a solution, but doesn't look like anyone will be able to answer, so I'll provide the info I can in case this happens to someone else.

The problem happens when previously logged in and wp-admin is trying to "reauthorize" (the parameter "reauth" is present in the URL).

The issue seems to have to do with serving WordPress over **MacOS's own Apache installation**, but works fine when serving over a **Mampstack** installation. (I had previously gone over to the MacOS built-in installation because I needed MySQL and not MariaDB, I guess I'll have to run them in parallel.)